# Eclipse -lcurl not find

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, libcurl

I need a special compiler. This is my call from eclipse:

```
powerpc-stw-linux-uclibc-g++ -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -L/usr/libx32 -L/var/lib -o "Test"  ./src/Test.o   -lz -lcurl
```

But now Eclipse throw this:

> /opt/powerpc-gcc-4.4.3-uclib/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc-stw-linux-uclibc/4.4.3/../../../../powerpc-stw-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: skipping incompatible   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcurl.so when searching for -lcurl
>   /opt/powerpc-gcc-4.4.3-uclib/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc-stw-linux-uclibc/4.4.3/../../../../powerpc-stw-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: skipping incompatible   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcurl.a when searching for -lcurl
>   /opt/powerpc-gcc-4.4.3-uclib/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc-stw-linux-uclibc/4.4.3/../../../../powerpc-stw-linux-uclibc/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl

I tried to compile under Ubuntu 14.04 x86. libcurl should be installed

```
$ curl-config --libs
-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lcurl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you are building for PowerPC, but linking with the lib for i386.

You need to download/build libcurl for PowerPC, and provide the correct path to it.

In other words, don't mix two different architectures.

Comment: I hope you do realize that your comments are not descriptive, and by looking at them people will not be able to help you?